# Can't understand this spoken sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, spoken-language

[I can't quite tell what the person is trying to say here:](https://youtu.be/9XWZfwJFz1U?t=14m31s)

今日は酒____悪いなー！

Something about the sake is bad but what? It almost sounds like he is saying ぐせ悪い but I can't find a word that would match that empty spot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) 今日は酒____悪いなー！
>   like he is saying ぐせ悪い

You know the answer.
The answer is:
今日{きょう}は酒{さけ}[ぐせ]{LLLL}悪{わる}いなー！
酒癖{さけぐせ} is the habit or 癖{くせ} somebody does when he/she drinks liquor (*Japanese sake*, beer, wine, etc.) too much.

酒癖{さけぐせ}が悪{わる}い人{ひと} : a bad drinker.  酒癖{さけぐせ}が悪{わる}い : to turn nasty when drunk

As for the given sentence (1), it is made from the sentence by omitting some words. These are the possible sentences from which sentence (1) is made:

> (2) 今日は、いつもの彼{かれ}と違{ちが}って酒癖が悪いなー！
>   Unlike usual, he is/seems a bad drinker today!
>   (3) 今日の彼{かれ}は酒癖が悪いなー！
>   Today he is/seems a bad drinker!

Comment: Sorry, while that does help a bit, I don't still quite understand the meaning of this sentence as a whole. Mainly my problem is that I don't see how this habit relates to the word today (if that makes any sense).

Comment: >Today he is/seems a bad drinker! I was thinking that it might be something along these lines but wasn't quite sure if I was understanding it right. Now I have my confirmation, thanks!

Comment: @Jinzal: If you are not sure if you are understanding it right, replace 彼  by あなた as: (2)' 今日は、いつものあなたと違って酒癖が悪いなー！ (3)' 今日のあなたは酒癖が悪いなー！